# How to use results from a sql query as a variable

Tags: mysql, sql, go, type-conversion

I'm trying to use a result from a query as an integer, so i can use it in some different calculations.

I'm fairly new at Go and programming in general(really new, just started school a few weeks back). For an assignment for school I need to calculate the 'doorlooptijd'(nr of months a customer has to pay) based on the customers age.
When i run below code i keep getting the error: 'cannot use leeftijdAlsText (type *sql.Rows) as type string in argument to strconv.Atoi'

```
leeftijd := "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, k.geboortedatum, NOW()) AS leeftijd FROM klant k WHERE k.klantnummer = ?"
leeftijdAlsText, err := db.Query(leeftijd, nummerKlant)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error found.")
    panic(err)
}
var huidigeLeeftijd int
if leeftijdAlsText.Next() {
    err := leeftijdAlsText.Scan(&leeftijdAlsText)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error found")
        panic(err)
    }
}
huidigeLeeftijd, _ = strconv.Atoi(leeftijdAlsText)
var doorlooptijd int
if huidigeLeeftijd < 45 {
    doorlooptijd = 120
} else if huidigeLeeftijd > 45 && huidigeLeeftijd < 55 {
    doorlooptijd = 90
} else if huidigeLeeftijd > 55 {
    doorlooptijd = 60
}
```

When this works, i need to insert the doorlooptijd in a new row in my database, together with some other information about the customer.

Comment: Don't pass the rows (`&leeftijdAlsText`) to the `Scan` method. Pass the int (`&huidigeLeeftijd`) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @mkopriva. I've tried what you said, but the program still gives the same error result

Comment: Keep in mind that Go is strongly typed language, i.e. you can't just use values of type A where type B is required. For example [`Query`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query) returns a value of type `*sql.Rows`, while [`strconv.Atoi`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi) takes an argument of type `string`, that's why you get the compile time error. `*sql.Rows` != `string`.

Comment: Also, as far as I understand `TIMESTAMPDIFF` returns an integer, therefore you should `Scan` the result into an integer, as already mentioned in the previous comment, and with that there is no need to use `strconv.Atoi`.

Comment: ... and, when using `*sql.Rows`, don't forget to close them https://play.golang.com/p/rmvqFFR3NQY, alternatively, when all you need is a single row, use `QueryRow` instead https://play.golang.com/p/DE3t8izSjFh (that's closed automatically when calling `Scan`).

Comment: Great, thanks lot! I think I understand a bit better what went wrong :)